# Switch the geometry of a mesh in real time three.js

Tags: javascript, geometry, three.js, webgl

I'm currently creating a mesh in three.js using the following:

```
sphereGeometry  = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 16,16 );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, material );
```

I've also created a torus:

```
torusGeometry   = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 1, 0.42 );
```

At any point in my animation loop, I want to be able to swap the sphere out for the torus. Is this possible? How do I swap one geometry for another?

Comment: Did you get the geometry switching to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in Three.js R59, setGeometry and setMaterial were removed again from Three.Mesh

What you can do to replace geometry is removing your Mesh from Scene and creating a new one with your new geometry and your old material and add it back to your scene. This will work for sure :)

Comment: how do you efficiently remove an object form the scene? Object3D.remove() does a linear scan of the children array : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L332

Answer (score 6):

Switching geometries can be costly. I would simply add both to the scene and hide / reveal based on your situation.

Comment: How can I hide geometry?

Comment: @BartekKosa Every [THREE.Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) has a `.visible` property. You can set it to `false` or `true` in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetGeometryCommand` to change the geometry of a Mesh in realtime.

Usage:

```
  editor.execute( new SetGeometryCommand( object, new THREE[ geometry.type ](
        radiusTop,
        radiusBottom,
        height,
        radialSegments,
        heightSegments,
        openEnded
    ) ) );
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/commands/SetGeometryCommand.js

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
// In this example we will distort a plane
let plane = new THREE.Mesh(g1, m1);
plane.rotation.x = Math.PI * 270 / 180;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = 0;
scene.add(plane);

// Distort plane
let positions = plane.geometry.attributes.position.array;
let count = positions.length / 3;

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let v = new THREE.Vector3(positions[i * 3], positions[i * 3 + 1], positions[i * 3 + 2]);
    let distanceFromCenterY = Math.abs(v.x) / 100;
    v.z += distanceFromCenterY > .2 ?
         (Math.random() * (20 - .15) + .15) * distanceFromCenterY * 2 :
         (Math.random() * (.8 - .2) + .2) + distanceFromCenterY;
    
    // In this example we are updating the z coordinate or ther vertices
    plane.geometry.attributes.position.array[ i * 3 + 2 ] = v.z;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try looking at this:  http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Objects/Mesh

Especially this method:

```
mesh.setGeometry(geometry)
```

Here is how you would do it inside your render loop (you set the flag whenever you want to swap the sphere out for the torus)

```
var flag;  
...
function render () {
    if (flag) {
        mesh.setGeometry(torusGeometry);
        flag = false;
    }
}
render();
```

If you want to flip back and forth (inside render loop):

```
if (conditions) { 
    mesh.setGeometry(sphereGeometry);
}

if (condition) {
    mesh.setGeometry(torusGeometry);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore... see answer below and accept + upvote